# How to list MAC Address of an AWS EC2 instance with Python and boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

how to find out information about MAC address of  Amazon EC2 instances using the Python boto3 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one network interface attached to your instances. If you have more than one network interface attached to your instances, tweak the code to your needs.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
insts = list(ec2.instances.all())
for inst in insts:
  for iface in inst.network_interfaces:
    print inst.instance_id, iface.mac_address
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, But it is giving MAC address of 'eth0' interface. I need the MAC address of all the interface of AWS EC2 instances ex: 'eth1' etc.      Thanks.

Comment: similarly how to fetch  IP  of eth0 , eth1 etc .. Could you please help me in this ..

Answer (score 5):

If you are on the instance itself, the MAC address can be retrieve via the [instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac/ 

02:72:f3:75:2f:83
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ips = []
    macs = []
    print self.nodes
    vpc = self.resource.Vpc(self.config['vpc_id'])

    for node in self.nodes:

        node_name = node.name
        if re.search(re.escape(instance_name) + r"-*[0-9]*", node_name) and node.state == 'running':
            ips.append(node.private_ips)

            for n in node.network_interfaces:
                if n.private_ip_address == node.private_ip_address:
                    macs.append(n.mac_address)
                    break
    return ips, macs
```